# Pipeline data for Nigeria?

Tags: data, oil-gas, pipe-network, nigeria

I am looking for oil and gas pipeline for Africa or Nigeria. I have tried searching the [global energy observatory platform](http://globalenergyobservatory.org/) and I cannot find it.

Comment: For Full access you need to register, did you register?

Answer (score 2):

Typing nothing more than "pipeline shapefile Nigeria" into google found [West African Existing and Proposed Pipelines at ArcGIS.com](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=79e940c72bef40709d131319b24001d7) as the top return.

Comment: Note: this data is 2 years old.